# Can't edit/propose Tag Wikis on Meta.Gaming.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

So, I thought it would be helpful to have a tag wiki for [hats](/questions/tagged/hats) here on Meta, because Tag Wikis are a good thing, and Hats is one of those tags that might actually benefit from some explanation.

Unfortunately, it would seem that I cannot propose or edit tag wikis here on meta. When I go to do so, the **Create Tag Wiki** button is there, but... it doesn't do anything. I can click it for hours on end like a Diablo player on speed with a mouse that has tape over it's laser, it doesn't matter, I don't get to make a tag wiki. I have 20k rep, so there shouldn't be any per-tag rep requirement involved here, and just to check, I went and looked at the wiki for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and clicking the **Edit** button for that wiki yields similar non-results.

[hats](/questions/tagged/hats) deserves a wiki. Why can't I give it a wiki?

Comment: I've merged [meta-tag:hats] into [meta-tag:hatdash] btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Now, it is the future, and [tag wikis on meta sites *can* be edited as usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066).

---

See [Jeff's answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2362/unable-to-propose-tag-wiki/2369#2369) on a similar topic on the Super User meta:

> We're not currently allowing tag wikis to be edited on metas, as we plan to push out the shared meta tag wikis from meta.so.
>
> This may change in the future.

Comment: Well in that case there shouldn't be a button for it.

Comment: Yeah well but there *is* so yeah

Comment: This also affects moderators by the way.